# disable 301 redirect for specific for specific pages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

I'm changing my domain **[www.old.com](http://www.old.com)** to **[www.new.com](http://www.new.com)**, for that m using **301** redirects via `.htaccess`, and it's working fine, but the issue is I don't want to redirect my specific pages.

for example **[www.old.com/my-account](http://www.old.com/my-account)** or **[www.old.com/checkout](http://www.old.com/checkout)**. Can someone help me out?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two obvious options:

You could add conditions to your existing rule:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-account/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/?$
RewriteRule ^ https://new.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or you could add exceptions that get applied *before* the general redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?my-account/?$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?checkout/?$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ https://new.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Both alternatives can be implemented in the http server's host configuration, or, if you have no access to that, in an distributed configuration file (".htaccess").

Comment: thank you very much both codes are working great..